# CSS for first element with class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the background of "zxczxczxc" and "bbbbbb" to yellow. I try ul > li:first-child > a  {
background: yellow;
} but it is not work. Any one have solution? thanks

Note: No add more class. It's must be css only.

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>
    <a>zxczxczxc</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a>ccccc</a></li>
        <li><a>bbbbddddddbb</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
        <a>bbbbbb</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm confused, I tried it in the answer snippets, your solution does work, could you show how you declare your css property?

Answer (score 0):

**Your Answer:**

```css
.link1{background-color:red}

.link2{background-color:Blue;
color:white;}
```

```html
    <li>
        <a class="link1">zxczxczxc</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a>ccccc</a></li>
            <li><a>bbbbddddddbb</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    
      <li>
            <a class="link2">bbbbbb</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can't add class for <a>. Any other solution?

Comment: replace the `class` with `style="background-color:red; color:white;"`

Comment: `<html> <head> </head> <style> <!--here is you can add css--></style> <body> <!--Contents--> </body </html>`

Comment: No I cant add any style or class anymore. The solution should be how to point to first ul and only get li in side ul. If inside li have ul or li. Just skip it.

Comment: actually, i have confused, what you want ??

Answer (score -2):

Buddy, you have a small typo in your code to set a background color we use `background-color`

```
body {
     background-color: coral;
}
```